# Stream processing of shop orders in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I learn stream processing data and wonder how data are joined in case when user makes order.

The order data is sent to Apache Flink. What if customer makes payment after some days. How Apache Flink does know that payment data is relative to before sending order data?

To be able join it and create a new aggregatred data for shippment?

Comment: It really depends on how you define your stream processing logic. You could create a window (session / tumbling) of the time the user can apply the payment logic, and only then emit the order downstream. You could also emit the order and save it in some stateful operator, and wait for the events payment to come through and then emit an upsert. It's really down to how you define your logic.

Comment: Thank you a lot, what if I choose the first described method, when I alocate time for payment? How to know that payment from user is relative to order?

Comment: You'd need some kind of identifier that correlates between the two.